# How to add zoom controls to an map image

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/delhi2">    

          <ZoomControls 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/ZoomControls01" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                   android:layout_gravity="right">
                 </ZoomControls>
                     </LinearLayout>
```

How to do add zoom controls and vertical and horizontal scrolling for an map image. i have put the image on the screen as background..please how to code

Answer (score 0):

you might need to put the image in an ImageView to be able to zoom it. then do this in code:

```
/* Set up the Zoom controls */
ImageView iview = (ImageView)findViewById(android.R.id.imageViewId);
FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

final View zoom = iview.getZoomControls();
mContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);
zoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Rgds
AJ

Comment: i am not able to do with the image view because it shows that getzoomcontrols are undefined for imageview